# What does the update_op return variable mean, in precision_at_k metric, in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have the following code:

```
>>> rel = tf.constant([[1, 5, 10]], tf.int64) # Relevant items for a user
>>> rec = tf.constant([[7, 5, 10, 6, 3, 1, 8, 12, 31, 88]], tf.int64) # Recommendations
>>>
>>> metric = tf.metrics.precision_at_k(rel, rec, 10)
>>>
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
>>> precision, update = sess.run(metric)
>>> precision
0.2
>>> update
0.2
```

So, the precision is calculated as:

```
# of relevant items recommended to the user / # of recommendations
```

My question is, what is the `update_op` variable that the function returns?

Answer (score 6):

Below is the example detailing how the two returns from `tf.metrics.precision_at_k` works.

```py
rel = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [1,3])
rec = tf.constant([[7, 5, 10, 6, 3, 1, 8, 12, 31, 88]], tf.int64) 
precision, update_op = tf.metrics.precision_at_k(rel, rec, 10)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

stream_vars = [i for i in tf.local_variables()]
#Get the local variables true_positive and false_positive

print(sess.run(precision, {rel:[[1,5,10]]})) # nan
#tf.metrics.precision maintains two variables true_positives 
#and  false_positives, each starts at zero.
#so the output at this step is 'nan'

print(sess.run(update_op, {rel:[[1,5,10]]})) #0.2
#when the update_op is called, it updates true_positives 
#and false_positives using labels and predictions.

print(sess.run(stream_vars)) #[2.0, 8.0]
# Get true positive rate and false positive rate

print(sess.run(precision,{rel:[[1,10,15]]})) # 0.2
#So calling precision will use true_positives and false_positives and outputs 0.2

print(sess.run(update_op,{rel:[[1,10,15]]})) #0.15
#the update_op updates the values to the new calculated value 0.15.

print(sess.run(stream_vars)) #[3.0, 17.0]
```

You run `update_op` at every batch and only when you want to check precision you evaluate `precision`.

Comment: How is the update_op variable being calculated? I mean, why is 0.2 at first and 0.15 later?

Comment: Because the inputs fed are different. The formula to calculate is tp/(tp+fp), i have added the code to get the local variables tp and fp.

Comment: But isn't the tp = 3, at first? I mean the values you pass for the labels (1, 5, 10) are all contained in the recommendations.

Comment: can you help me with the above comment?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

From [`tf.metrics.precision_at_k`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/precision_at_k) documentation:

> Returns:
>
> - **`precision`**: Scalar float64 Tensor with the value of
>     `true_positives` divided by the sum of `true_positives` and
>     `false_positives`.
> - **`update_op`**: Operation that increments `true_positives`
>     and `false_positives` variables appropriately, and whose value matches
>     precision.

Comment: sure, but what does it mean? I can't get it!

Comment: As the doc explains, there are two variables behind the scene, which are used to compute the precision. Tensorflow provides an op to increment them (useful for streaming data). Can you detail your question?

Answer (score 0):

answer the comment

```
import tensorflow as tf

rel = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [1,3])
rec = tf.constant([[7, 5, 10, 6, 3, 1, 8, 12, 31, 88]], tf.int64)


k = 10
precision, update_op = tf.metrics.precision_at_k(rel, rec, k)
tmp_rank = tf.nn.top_k(rec, k)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

stream_vars = [i for i in tf.local_variables()]
#Get the local variables true_positive and false_positive
print("[TMP_RANK]: ", sess.run(tmp_rank))
print("[PRECSION_1]: ",sess.run(precision, {rel:[[1,5,10]]})) # nan
#tf.metrics.precision maintains two variables true_positives 
#and  false_positives, each starts at zero.
#so the output at this step is 'nan'

print("[UPDATE_OP_1]:",sess.run(update_op, {rel:[[1,5,10]]})) #0.2
#when the update_op is called, it updates true_positives 
#and false_positives using labels and predictions.

print("[STREAM_VARS_1]:",sess.run(stream_vars)) #[2.0, 8.0]
# Get true positive rate and false positive rate

print("[PRECISION_1]:",sess.run(precision,{rel:[[1,10,15]]})) # 0.2
#So calling precision will use true_positives and false_positives and outputs 0.2

print("[UPDATE_OP_2]:",sess.run(update_op,{rel:[[1,10,15]]})) #0.15
#the update_op updates the values to the new calculated value 0.15.

print("[STREAM_VARS_2]:",sess.run(stream_vars)) #[3.0, 17.0]
```

the output is:

```
[TMP_RANK]:  TopKV2(values=array([[88, 31, 12, 10,  8,  7,  6,  5,  3,  1]]), indices=array([[9, 8, 7, 2, 6, 0, 3, 1, 4, 5]], dtype=int32))
[PRECSION_1]:  nan
[UPDATE_OP_1]: 0.2
[STREAM_VARS_1]: [2.0, 8.0]
[PRECISION_1]: 0.2
[UPDATE_OP_2]: 0.15
[STREAM_VARS_2]: [3.0, 17.0]
```

note the indices of TMP_RANK
Rec represents probability, so the value of rel should be compared with the indices of rec.