# how to use tf.metrics.recall_at_k properly?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a bit confused therefore I need your help and leading!

I am having a sample dataset. I have 2 sources and 4 targets as shown in the following matrix. Each cell is representing a score from a source and a target.

[image]

Ground T Label for S1=T1, 
Ground T Label for S2=T3

If I am not wrong, the recall@k is calculated like the following:

the recall@1 result for S1 and S2 should be 0 + 0 = 0 (Since S1 and S2 do  not have the highest top-1 scores to the Ground T labels)

Likewise, the recall@2 result for S1 and S2 should be 0 + 0 = 0 (Since S1 and S2's top 2 results are still not containing the Ground T labels)

Finally, the recall@3 result for S1 and S2 should be 1 + 1 = 1 (Since S1 and S2's top 3 results are now containing the Ground T labels)

If I am correct, could you please lead me how to implement this toy example in tensorflow (estimator API) by using **tf.metrics.recall_at_k** or **tf.metrics.recall_at_top_k** *(I do not know the exact differences between them)* to have the same result as I showed?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's talk about the difference between `tf.metrics.recall_at_k` and `tf.metrics.recall_at_top_k`.

If you look at open source code, you will find `precision_at_k` is a simple wrapper around `precision_at_top_k`. `precision_at_k` applies `tf.nn.top_k` first, and then calls `precision_at_top_k`. Documentation shows that `precision_at_k` expects a float tensor of logits values, but `precision_at_top_k` expects integer tensor the predictions to be the indices of the top k classes.

So if your value is a logit score values, you should use `precision_at_k`.

There are also some mistakes in the calculation method. When you calculate `recall@1` result for S1 and S2 should be (0 + 0)/2=0 (Since S1 has the highest top-1 score to T4 label not to the ground T1 and S2 has the highest top-1 score to T1 not to the Ground T3 label).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

y_true = np.array([ [0], [2]]).astype(np.int64)
y_true = tf.identity(y_true)
y_pred = np.array([[1, 2, 1, 4],
                   [3, 2, 1, 0]
                   ]).astype(np.float32)
y_pred = tf.identity(y_pred)
k = 1
_, update_recall = tf.metrics.recall_at_k(y_true, y_pred, k)

tmp_rank = tf.nn.top_k(y_pred, k)
stream_vars = [i for i in tf.local_variables()]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    print("update_recall: ",sess.run(update_recall ))
    print("STREAM_VARS: ",(sess.run(stream_vars)))
    print("TMP_RANK: ",sess.run(tmp_rank))

#print
update_recall:  0.0
STREAM_VARS:  [0.0, 2.0]
TMP_RANK:  TopKV2(values=array([[4.],
       [3.]], dtype=float32), indices=array([[3],
       [0]], dtype=int32))
```

You can try to change the value of k to see the `recall@k`.

Comment: Thank you so much @giser_yugang, it is exactly what I was looking for. By the way, thank you for fixing my toy example where I mis-indicated the index of the true label. Let me also fix my original post.

Comment: The original document refers to recall and update_op as return objects. Should I also take the result from the update_recall object while using tf.Estimator?

Comment: @TheWho I don't use `tf.Estimator` very much. You can see this question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50291916/what-does-the-update-op-return-variable-mean-in-precision-at-k-metric-in-tenso/50292692#50292692) about the difference between `recall` and `update_op`. `precision` and `recall` are similar at this point.